# memoryerror when i try to convert to json a postgres result query

Tags: python, json, flask, psycopg2

i'm trying to convert the results to json of a postgres database,it works! but doesnt finish and it triggers an error

rows 984288

```
 try:

        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("select * from daily")
        row_headers = [x[0] for x in cur.description]
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        json_data = []
        for result in rows:
            json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,result)))
        # rows = [dict((cur.description[i][0], value) \
        #           for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cur.fetchall()]
        print("the number of parts: ", cur.rowcount)
        conn.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()

    return json.dumps(json_data)
```

debug:

[image]

error:

out of memory for query result

### 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Aug/2020 02:12:18] "GET /pruebas HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59545)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug_*init*_.py", line 304, in debug_application
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in **call**
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
File "C:\Users\iscca\PycharmProjects\covid-uabc\main.py", line 114, in pruebas
cosa = Prueba()
File "C:\Users\iscca\PycharmProjects\covid-uabc\pruebas.py", line 14, in **init**
self.rows = self.enlistar(conn)
File "C:\Users\iscca\PycharmProjects\covid-uabc\pruebas.py", line 38, in enlistar
return json.dumps(json_data)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'json_data' referenced before assignment

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 323, in run_wsgi
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 314, in execute
for data in application_iter:
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug_*init*_.py", line 344, in debug_application
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py", line 344, in render_full
"summary": self.render_summary(include_title=False),
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py", line 314, in render_summary
frames = [group.render(mark_lib=mark_lib) for group in self.groups]
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py", line 314, in 
frames = [group.render(mark_lib=mark_lib) for group in self.groups]
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py", line 435, in render
frame.render(mark_lib=mark_lib),
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py", line 485, in render
"lines": self.render_line_context(),
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py", line 504, in render_line_context
before, current, after = self.get_context_lines()
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py", line 611, in get_context_lines
before = self.sourcelines[self.lineno - context - 1 : self.lineno - 1]
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\utils.py", line 90, in **get**
value = self.func(obj)
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py", line 608, in sourcelines
return source.decode(charset, "replace").splitlines()
MemoryError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

### Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\iscca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "C:\Users\iscca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "C:\Users\iscca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in **init**
self.handle()
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 345, in handle
File "C:\Users\iscca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\http\server.py", line 426, in handle
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 379, in handle_one_request
return self.run_wsgi()
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 340, in run_wsgi
self.server.log("error", "Error on request:\n%s", traceback.plaintext)
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\utils.py", line 90, in **get**
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py", line 353, in plaintext
return u"\n".join([group.render_text() for group in self.groups])
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py", line 353, in 
return u"\n".join([group.render_text() for group in self.groups])
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py", line 446, in render_text
out.append(frame.render_text())
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py", line 500, in render_text
self.current_line.strip(),
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py", line 618, in current_line
return self.sourcelines[self.lineno - 1]
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\utils.py", line 90, in **get**
value = self.func(obj)
File "C:\Users\iscca.virtualenvs\covid-uabc-YDkkGE3-\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py", line 579, in sourcelines
source = f.read()
MemoryError

Comment: It Is already imported, that's a warning because I'm returning a variable that could be null

Comment: Solved, i updated to python 3.8 and arch x64 because exists a restriction on memory usages, i installed memory profile to measure my memory